# Where can I ask about Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Hyperledger Fabric is an open-source enterprise-grade permissioned distributed ledger technology (DLT) platform. Where I can ask a question for the same?

Is there a specific community?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gnat: As the answer there doesn't mention blockchains, distributed ledgers, or anything similar, I'm pretty skeptical that it's a suitable dupe for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technology has its own non Stack Exchange Community: https://chat.hyperledger.org/ or https://lists.hyperledger.org/ You'll likely find the greatest concentration of experts there, particularly if you're just trying to find out more about the technology rather than having a specific issue with it.

While there is a [hyperleger](/questions/tagged/hyperleger) tag on the Etherium site but [this meta question](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/are-questions-about-hyperledger-fabric-on-topic) suggests that most such questions are off-topic there and should rather be asked on the [Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) site. See that site's [tour](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information but it suggests that

> Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, ZCash, Dogecoin, and NXT.

would be on-topic

Additionally, some questions of a more programming nature have been asked on Stack Overflow. There's a [hyperleger-fabric](/questions/tagged/hyperleger-fabric) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-fabric) there.